# Excluding all URLs containing a specific word

Tags: search, google-search

Suppose I enter the following search string:

```
msdn proxy website
```

I get a list of results that contains (among other results) sites which have the word `msdn` in their URL. What if I want to exclude these sites?

The following doesn’t work:

```
msdn proxy website -allinurl:msdn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `allinurl` use `inurl`.

Samples:

`sherlock holmes inurl:wikipedia`

`sherlock holmes -inurl:wikipedia`

Ok, fine... I'll use your example:

`msdn proxy website -inurl:msdn`